# formula for Financial year with date in excel

Tags: excel-formula

i want formula for following like if i put date like 01/04/2014 then i want date as start of Financial year which comes to 01/04/2014 but if date is like 01/11/2013 then it should give result as 01/04/2013

Thanks,
Shreyas

Comment: Could you please be more specific and show what you've tried so far? See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you put your date in A1:

```
=IF(A1<DATE(YEAR(A1),4,1),DATE(YEAR(A1)-1,4,1),DATE(YEAR(A1),4,1))
```